# Accept filename as argument and calculate repeated words along with count

Tags: bash, shell

I need to find the number or repeated characters from a text file and need to pass filename as argument.

Example:
`test.txt` data contains

```
Zoom
```

Output should be like:

```
z 1
o 2
m 1
```

I need a command that will accept filename as argument and then lists the number of characters from that file. In my example I have a test.txt which has `zoom` word. So the output will be like how many times each letter has repeated.

My attempt:

vi test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="$1" --to pass filename as argument
sort file1.txt | uniq -c --to count the number of letters
```

Comment: Note that you can always use `echo` to check the content of a variable. Also note that `sort` and `uniq` only work with lines, not with single characters.

Comment: @mashuptwice How to give it a try?

Comment: How to give what a try?

Comment: @mashuptwice How to pass a filename as argument and count the numbers?

Comment: Passing an argument to your script should work fine the way you did it with `$1`. Counting would require additional information from you: You stated that you want to count the occurrences of a word in your text file. In your example you are counting the occurrences of characters in a word. As you can see your phrasing is contradictory. Also it is unclear what role `externalprogram` plays in your script.

Comment: @mashuptwice ```externalprogram``` I thought to use to pass filename as argument. Since, I am new to shell script to was trying to solve the problem. Also, I used the command ```grep -o -i needs test.txt | wc -l``` but this is also not giving me the count

Comment: `wc` by default also counts lines.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243329/discussion-between-vicky-and-mashuptwice).

Comment: Please edit your question and 1. clarify your exact goal with the script 2. add enough sample input data, eg. parts of your `file1.txt` 3. add a detailed description of the problems you are facing

Comment: You are still writing that you want to count the occurences of a word in a file. Also: Does your file always contain just a single word?

Comment: It's not  clear what you want.  Ignoring the very confusing question text, the title suggests that given a filename you want counts of the repeated words in it.  Does this do anything like what you want: `tr -sc '[:alpha:]' '\n' <"$1" | sort | uniq -dc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#get the argument for further processing
inputfile="$1"

#check if file exists
if [ -f $inputfile ]
then
    #convert file to a usable format
                    #convert all characters to lowercase
                                                 #put each character on a new line
                                                                            #output to temporary file
    cat $inputfile | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' > tmp.txt
    #loop over every character from a-z
    for char in {a..z}
    do
        #count how many times a character occurs
        count=$(grep -c "$char" tmp.txt)
        #print if count > 0
        if [ "$count" -gt "0" ]
        then
            echo -e "$char" "$count"
        fi
    done
    rm tmp.txt
else
    echo "file not found!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess?

```sh
cat test.txt |
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |
fold -w 1 |
sort |
uniq -c |
awk '{print $2, $1}'
```

```
m 1
o 2
z 1
```

Comment: I completely forgot about `uniq -c` when writing my answer. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I would reach for `grep -o .` but `fold` is awesome

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting `awk` script that count all kinds of chars:

```
awk '
BEGIN{FS = ""}  # make each char a field
{
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { # iteratre over all fields in line
    ++charsArr[$i]; # count each field occourance in array
  }
}
END {
  for (char in charsArr) { # iterrate over chars array
    printf("%3d %s\n", charsArr[char], char);  # cournt char-occourances and the char
  }
}' |sort -n
```

Or in one line:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)++arr[$i]}END{for(char in arr)printf("%3d %s\n",arr[char],char)}' FS="" input.1.txt|sort -n
```